# Find the minimum distance between the curves (Y - 2)² = 8(X - 4.5) and (X - 4)² = 4(Y - 6)

Tags: geometry

Find the minimum distance between the curves **(Y - 2)² = 8(X - 4.5)** and **(X - 4)² = 4(Y - 6)**

Attempt:- The minimum distance between these two **parabolas** lies along their **common normal**.

Relevant equations:-

Normal to C1: **Y - 2 = M1 (X - 4.5) - 4 M1 - 2 M1³**

Normal to C2: **X - 4 = M2 (Y - 6 )  - 2 M2 - 2 M2³**
Since these both equations represent the same line, comparing the coefficients of X and Y we get,

1. **M1 * M2 =1**

2.**- 8.5 M1 - 2 M1³ +2 = -4 / M2 + 2 M2² + 8**

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209893/minimum-distance-between-two-parabolas

Comment: There we have symmetry between the curves and i need to this using co normals