# Proving that the shortest distance between two parabolas is along their common normal.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Can someone prove that the minimum distance between two non-intersecting parabolas is along their common normal (without calculus)? (If I understand how to prove it, I'll prove it myself for other curves too.)

Comment: I believe you must use calculus to prove it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209893/minimum-distance-between-two-parabolas

Comment: This is not true if the parabolas intersect.

Comment: Or if they're nested like $y=x^2$ and $y=x^2+1$.  Note that in this case a shortest connection does not exist in the (Euclidean) plane.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the existence of a shortest distance, let the shortest distance join points $A$ and $B$ and construct a circle with diameter $AB$. If the circle cuts either parabola at a point other than $A$ or $B$ there is a line joining the two curves which is shorter than the diameter. Else the circle must be tangent at points $A$ and $B$ and the diameter $AB$ is normal to both curves (because the diameter is perpendicular to the tangent).

There are some implicit assumptions here, but would this do? Note that if $A=B$ then the diameter doesn't have a fixed direction and the situation is different.

Comment: You don't explain how to find points $A,\;B$

Comment: @Raffaele No - I assume their existence (see very first comment in answer) and show that if they exist they are joined by a common normal. (Implicit assumptions include that the parabolas do not cross). If there is a shortest distance, there are points which are that distance apart.